# JavaFX: Moving a circle with Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to create an animation, but without using built in features like TranslateTransition. On an Anchor Pane I created a circle, and I want it to move constantly along some line like this:

```
 public void initialize()  {  
        MyThread task = new MyThread();
        new Thread(task).start();  
    }
```

```
class MyThread extends Task<Integer>
{
    @FXML
    Circle myCircle;
    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception
    {
        int i= 737; //starting position
        while(true)
        {
            ((Node) myCircle).setLayoutX(i);
            i--;
            if(i%109==0) //ending position
                i=737;

        }
    }

}
```

But it doesn't move at all. I'm new to threads in javaFX, so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. But when I just printed some numbers out like this it worked just fine:

```
class MyThread extends Task<Integer>
{
    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {
            count(i);
            count10(i);
        }

    protected void count(int i)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    protected void count10(int i)
    {
        System.out.println(10*i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX nodes should only be modified from the JavaFX application thread. You're modifying the `layoutX` property from a background thread which yields unreliable results.

You can update the `value` property and use a listener for the `Task.value` property to take care of the synchronisation for you:

```
class MyThread extends Task<Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception {
        final int minX = (737 / 109) * 109; // use rounding of integer division to find greatest int <= 737 divisible by 109

        while(true) {
            for (int i = 737; i >= minX; i--) {
                updateValue(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
MyThread task = new MyThread();
task.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> circle.setLayoutX(newValue.doubleValue()));
new Thread(task).start();
```

Note that the results of this code could be quite unpredictable: There is no delay between updates so the value at the time the binding is updated is likely to be random...

---

Otherwise you have to use `Platform.runLater` to update the GUI, but this is quite tricky with your code, since you do updates with a high enough frequency that JavaFX won't be able to cope with all the `Runnable`s submitted.

I do recommend using a JavaFX class like [`AnimationTimer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) instead. These kind of classes are provided to be used. Trying to implement something like this yourself is likely to be more trouble than it's worth, especially as inexperienced programmer.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I'm trying to make much more complex animation, and I don't think that I can do that with bulit in animations. This code was just to test threads in JavaFX.

Comment: Also I'm getting ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Circle.layoutX : A bound value cannot be set.``` when I try your code.

Comment: @NotStudent For some reason `AnchorPane` relocates the child even if there are no constraints set. You either need to use a `Pane` as parent instead or use a listener for the updates (code for the later edited into the question).

Comment: Very useful answer - I must admit that being new to Java I find the Observable class pretty intimidating